# redirect on ng-change in select tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-options

How do i pass the groupId in the below code

```
<select ng-options="group.id as group.name for group in groups" 
        ng-model="groupId" ng-controller="redirectCtrl" 
        ng-change="go('group/list/{{groupId}}')">
```

Comment: seems like `go` is a function of yours, why not adding a second parameter like `go('group/list/',groupId)`. Coding in your view is not the best for MVVM pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need (or no point) to use interpolation in `ng-change` expression just use a valid expression to construct the argument to be passed in:

Try:

```
 ng-change="go('group/list/' + groupId)"
```

Comment: how do i set the selected on load

Comment: You will have to set the ng-model with the default groups id. ex: `$scope.groupId = groups[0].id`  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70015/discussion-between-awebdeveloper-and-psl).